# Wordpress php sending data to local server

Tags: php, wordpress

If I have a wordpress website, and a user on the website enters some survey information, is it possible to send the results to a local server inside a company (assuming the website is hosted on some other companies server).  From looking around I see people using the JSON formats and GET, PUT etc.. but I havent seen this demonstrated with wordpress.  Is there a standard way to do this?  I can see it is possible to send via emails, but I was hoping for something more like TCP/IP communications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it must run through the front-ends WordPress installation, then the easiest way to be a simple HTTP POST request to a server you control. PHP has several different ways you can accomplish this with minimal effort.

The other way you can do this is just to set up a form that will send an AJAX response to your server. Just make sure your receiving server is configured to allow the originating domain.